# Algorithm for decomposing an element of a free Lie algebra in terms of Hall basis

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

Let $L(x,y)$ be the free Lie algebra generated by the Hall basis. We assume  $\deg(x) =2$ and $\deg(y) =2$ and for any $\alpha, \beta \in L(x,y)$ we have $\deg([\alpha, \beta])= \deg(\alpha)+\deg(\beta)-1$.

We know that for any $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma \in L(x,y)$ the Lie algebra satisfies the following properties:

1. $[\alpha, \beta] = (-1)^{\deg(\alpha)\deg(\beta)}[\beta, \alpha]$;
2. $(-1)^{\deg(\alpha)\deg(\gamma)}[[\alpha, \beta],\gamma]+(-1)^{\deg(\beta)\deg(\alpha)}[[\beta, \gamma],\alpha] +(-1)^{\deg(\gamma)\deg(\beta)}[[\gamma,\alpha],\beta]=0$;
3. $[\alpha,[y,y]]= (-1)^{(\deg(\alpha)+1)}2[[\alpha, y],y]$.

Is there any algorithm available such that any element $\alpha \in L(x,y)$ can be written as $\sum_{\alpha} x_{\alpha} h_{\alpha}$, where $h_{\alpha}$ is the Hall basis of $L(x,y)?$

For example, consider the element $\alpha= [[[[y,x],x],[y,x]],[y,y]] \in L(x,y)$. Then using properties (2) and (1) we can decompose $\alpha$ as

$$-2[[[[y,x],y],y],[[y,x],x]]-2[[[[[y,x],x],y],y],[y,x]]$$

Note that here the terms $[[[[y,x],y],y],[[y,x],x]], [[[[[y,x],x],y],y],[y,x]]$ are members of the Hall basis of $L(x,y)$. (I consider $x<y$.)

Comment: What you call (free) Lie algebra is not a Lie algebra. It seems to be a Lie superalgebra. Also your equalities only make sense for $\alpha,\beta$ homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

You can find such an algorithm in the book [1], starting from Chapter 4. It would be difficult to summarise the content of this book in a post.

[1] Reutenauer, Christophe. *Free Lie algebras*, London Mathematical Society Monographs. New Series, 7. Oxford Science Publications. The Clarendon Press, Oxford University Press, New York, 1993. xviii+269 pp. ISBN: 0-19-853679-8

Comment: On page 94 of your reference,  there is a similar kind of algorithm. But the main problem is: there, the author assumed that $[\alpha, \alpha] =0$ for any $\alpha \in L(x,y).$ But in my case $[\alpha, \alpha]=0$ only when $deg(\alpha)$ is odd. Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: @Surojit the first issue seems to be that the question is not well-posed.